# How to divide full name text from textfield into two strings(firstname and secondname) in swift

Tags: json, swift, uitextfield

I have one textfield called `fullnameTextField` here i am writing firstname space secondname in textfield

while parsing i need firstname separately and secondname separately,

**how to add firstname and secondname parameters from one `fullnameTextField`**

```
     @IBOutlet weak var fullName : UITextField!
```

and my api parameters are

```
let param =     ["fname" : "hello",
                 "lname": "test",
                 "country_code": "1",
                 "password" : txtPassword.text?.trim() ?? "",
                 "password_confirmation" : txtConfirmPassword.text?.trim() ?? "",
                 "phone" : mobileNum
                ]
```

how to add one input to two parameters

Comment: If your textfield allow only one space then you can use this : for first name ```fullName.text?.components(separatedBy: " ").first``` and for last name ```fullName.text?.components(separatedBy: " ").last```

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for this

If You need 2 fields for any other services(Stripe, etc) only way is use 2 inputs

We have too many variables of full names. It can contain 2 - 5 words or like utf16 symbols string (japanese, arabic).

Also Full name field not forcing to write first name in first, so even if u have 2 basic words, after separating it by whitespace u can be sure which one this parts is